# Localhost not working mac terminal

Tags: php, macos, terminal, localhost

Trying to run localhost to test a website in mac osx terminal.

```
andys-mbp:test Andy$ cd /Users/Andy/Desktop/test 
andys-mbp:test Andy$ php -S localhost:8000
```

This would usually work, but now I'm getting this error message:

> **Warning**:  Unknown: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known in **Unknown** on line **0**
>   [Tue Feb 24 12:55:58 2015] Failed to listen on localhost:8000 (reason: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known)

I've followed [this tutorial](http://php.about.com/od/phpbasics/ss/installMac_4.htm#step-heading) to make sure PHP and apache are running, but it didn't seem to help...

How can I fix this? Any help very much appreciated!

Comment: What does it say if you change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Is localhost even known? Try to `ping localhost` and see if it returns a result. If not, you must bind localhost to ip 127.0.0.1

Comment: `ping: cannot resolve localhost: Unknown host`

Comment: I get the same error with 127.0.0.1

Comment: Do you also get the error with the IPv6 localhost ip address? e.g.  php -S [::1]:8000

Comment: @justAnotherUser - that seems to be fine, I get this `PHP 5.4.24 Development Server started at Tue Feb 24 13:30:43 2015
Listening on http://[::1]:8000
Document root is /Users/Andy/Desktop/test
Press Ctrl-C to quit.` Although there is no document found when putting localhost:8000 into chrome.

Comment: What is the content of your `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname` files?

Comment: @vervas `##
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting. Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1 localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1 localhost
fe80::1%lo0 localhost`

Comment: "sudo ifconfig -a" should show both inet and inet6 localhost ip addresses under the "lo0" loopback interface.  If you're not seeing an entry for "inet 127.0.0.1" you can re-add it with "sudo ifconfig  lo0 add 127.0.0.1"....   otherwise have you tried rebooting ;)

Comment: `lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
 options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
 inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
 inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
 inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
 nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>`

Comment: Have restarted and repaired permissions.... Still can't get it to work.

Answer (score 8):

i think this guy has the same problem of you.. http://goo.gl/LQ0RgM

maybe you just need update your `/etc/hosts`, like commented on link:

The problem was with the host file. Fixed it by adding this to the `/etc/hosts` file:

> 127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
>   127.0.1.1   <hostname>

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I reset the hosts file but unfortunately, it hasn't fixed the problem. Its very strange because it was working yesterday, and I haven't messed around with hosts since then

Answer (score 0):

Used ls -la on the /etc folder, and found the permissions were a bit strange on the hosts file... Restarted and all fine now... Thanks everyone for your help... very strange.